# how to reset the formatting functions in cout using setw and setfill multiple time

Tags: c++

How can I use io manipulators like `setfill` and `setw` repeatedly without wrecking the output that happens below the other what I'm asking is I want to create a text based window not using win32 functions but a made version in command prompt I'm trying to use IO manipulators to create the shape of the window using a character I have selected in my program but what happens is

```
cout  <<setfill(width) << setfill(style)
```

want to fill the top with x's and the leave the bottom alone and setfill the bottom of the title bar variable

```
cout  <<endl<< titleBar << setw(width) << "[_][]][x]" << endl;
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std; 


class window
{
    public:
    window(const char * title)
    {
        windowTitle = title;
    }

    void createWindow(int width,int height,char windowStyle,const char * titleBar,const char * windowClass)
    {
        char style = windowStyle;
        cout <<setw(width) <<setfill(style) <<setw(0) <<endl;
        cout << titleBar << setw(width) << "[_][]][x]" <<endl;
        cout <<setw(width) <<setfill(style) <<setw(0) <<endl;
    }

    const char * getTitle() const { return windowTitle; }                 
    private:
    const char * windowTitle;
    const char * windowClass;

};

int main ()
{
    window myWindow("Windows Programming");
    myWindow.createWindow(50,100,'x',myWindow.getTitle(),"windowclass");

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try calling `setw(0)` to "reset" it?

Comment: i tryed it now the within the middle of the window title bar name x's occupy the space.

Comment: It's going to be easier to figure this out if you show us your exact, complete code that shows the problem.

Comment: im not sure how to add code in stackoverflow i tried but it gave me an error saying i have to indent i dont know what the means so i left it out

Comment: Indent = 4 spaces before the text of the code starts.  Each line of code must have the spaces in front.  Crap, I'm  just learning linux and can't figure out how to start a new line to demonstrate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say I fully comprehend the question, but resetting the fill and width could be done as shown:

```
void createWindow(int width,int height,char windowStyle,const char * titleBar,const char * windowClass)
{
    char style = windowStyle;

    char prev_char = cout.fill(style);

    cout << setw(width) << "" << endl;

    cout.fill(prev_char);

    cout << titleBar << setw(width - strlen(titleBar)) << "[_][]][x]" <<endl;

    cout << setw(width) << setfill(style) << "" << endl;
}
```

The main idea is to use the corresponding member functions from cout which return the previous value which you can later use to reset the fill/width. Running this code would yield the following result:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Windows Programming                      [_][]][x]
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Update:

I have updated the code so I can give you a better explanation.

the functions setw and setfill basically modify some of the internal flags/variables of the std::ostream. setfill permanently modifies the fill character, but setw only modifies the width for the next element. So let's analyse the code.

Instead of using setfill, I am calling directly the method from the std::ostream to set the fill value. The main reason I do this is because it returns the previous value it contained so I can restore later:

```
char prev_char = cout.fill(style);
```

The next step is to print the "title bar" or however you wan't to call it. To do so I set the width with *setw* to the parameter provided. As I said before the width is only applied to the next printed element, hence the *width* characters of value *style* are printed before the empty string:

```
cout << setw(width) << "" << endl;
```

In the next line we just recover the original fill value, which is very likely just a space:

```
cout.fill(prev_char);
```

Then we print the titlebar and the buttons, but we apply a new width so that we can fill the space between the titlebar text and the buttons with white spaces:

```
cout << titleBar  << setw(width - strlen(titleBar)) << "[_][]][x]" <<endl;
```

Finally, we print another line of *x's* of size *width*, but since we already have the original fill character stored in a variable, we can directly use the setfill function:

```
cout << setw(width) << setfill(style) << "" << endl;
```

Comment: any books on this kind of stuff

Comment: I guess any STL book covering ostreams should include relevant information.

Comment: If the answer provided the information you were looking for, please accept it by clicking the check mark, thanks.